# JQuery breakup action and do another instead

Tags: jquery

My problem is to find a fitting search-phrase to my question.
I think there are some answers in this forum about that.

I'd like to start a mouseOver event that acts to the fitting action intime. Currently when I'm hovering and leaving the one-div it performs first the mouseenter and after it is completed it does the mouseleave.

What I need is that at the time I leave the one-div with the mouse. The mouseleave event should instantly be activated.

I know it has something to do with the .ready function but I could not find any other.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#one").mouseenter(function() {
        $("div#two").slideDown("normal");
    });
    $("div#one").mouseleave(function() {
        $("div#two").slideUp("normal");
    });
});
```

Comment: Did not get what you are trying to achieve but Why do you think the mouseleave event isnt called immediately ?

Comment: I didnt get your question. But doing `$("div#two").stop().slideDown("normal");` and ` `$("div#two").stop()slideUp("normal");` helps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, might It help you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#one").mouseenter(function() {
        $("div#two").stop().slideDown("normal");
    });
    $("div#one").mouseleave(function() {
        $("div#two").stop().slideUp("normal");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The mouseenter and mouseleave are working fine, it's the animations that you keep queueing without stopping the queue. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#one").mouseenter(function() {
        $("div#two").stop(true, true).slideDown("normal");
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $("div#two").stop(true, true).slideUp("normal");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to abort the current running animation.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VN6FD/)